# Custom menu: Link names

Tags: theme-development, menus

I would like to build a wordpress theme with a custom menu (no dropdowns, nothing fancy). I am trying to get `wp_nav_menu` do what I want, but I can't quite see how to achieve the following.

I would like to give the menu items different names, i.e. if I have a page called `Classes`, I would like the link in the menu to be called `clAssEs` (which I will style to be rendered in a different font).

Should I use custom fields for this?

P.S.: Looking at the html output, the classes of my menu list items are `page_item` and `page-item-21`. Does this mean I am doing something wrong? This looks more like it is generated by `wp_page_menu`.

I am calling `wp_nav_menu` with

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array(
  'theme_location' => 'main-menu',
  'menu_class' => 'menu',
  'container_id' => 'none',
  'fallback_cb' => 'wp_page_menu'
)); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add other classes to individual menu items manually.

Within the Appearance->Menus page, click Screen Options in the top right corner.

You will see a menu that looks like this:

[image: Custom Menu Classes]

Check off `CSS Classes` and it will give you an extra form field per page item. Adding a custom class will allow you to target each specific list element with CSS of JavaScript on the front-end.

You can change the names of your menu items manually as well. They do not have to mirror the actual page names.